# Solr6 fails to add a core, shows following error

Tags: tomcat, solr, dataimporthandler, solr6, solrconfig

I am using solr 6.3.0 on redhat machine, integrated with tomcat server. One of my core is not getting added. The core imports data from a SQL Server database.
The `solr.log` files prints the following message.

Can someone help finding me, what is actually wrong?

```
2016-12-23 06:55:17.023 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.h.a.CoreAdminOperation core create command schema=schema.xml&dataDir=data&name=allprojects&action=CREATE&config=solrconfig.xml&instanceDir=allprojects&wt=json&_=1482419054659
2016-12-23 06:55:17.026 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader [null] Added 3 libs to classloader, from paths: [/home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects/lib]
2016-12-23 06:55:17.065 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader [allprojects] Added 56 libs to classloader, from paths: [/home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects/lib, /home/iipadmin/TN-Project-Search/solr-6.3.0/contrib/clustering/lib, /home/iipadmin/TN-Project-Search/solr-6.3.0/contrib/extraction/lib, /home/iipadmin/TN-Project-Search/solr-6.3.0/contrib/langid/lib, /home/iipadmin/TN-Project-Search/solr-6.3.0/contrib/velocity/lib, /home/iipadmin/TN-Project-Search/solr-6.3.0/dist]
2016-12-23 06:55:17.135 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Using Lucene MatchVersion: 6.3.0
2016-12-23 06:55:17.262 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema [allprojects] Schema name=example-data-driven-schema
2016-12-23 06:55:17.488 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Loaded schema example-data-driven-schema/1.6 with uniqueid field id
2016-12-23 06:55:17.508 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Creating SolrCore 'allprojects' using configuration from instancedir /home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects
2016-12-23 06:55:17.509 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [[allprojects] ] Opening new SolrCore at [/home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects], dataDir=[/home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects/data/]
2016-12-23 06:55:17.511 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.r.XSLTResponseWriter xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
2016-12-23 06:55:17.529 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.u.UpdateHandler Using UpdateLog implementation: org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog
2016-12-23 06:55:17.530 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.u.UpdateLog Initializing UpdateLog: dataDir= defaultSyncLevel=FLUSH numRecordsToKeep=100 maxNumLogsToKeep=10 numVersionBuckets=65536
2016-12-23 06:55:17.532 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Hard AutoCommit: if uncommited for 15000ms; 
2016-12-23 06:55:17.532 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Soft AutoCommit: disabled
2016-12-23 06:55:17.534 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.s.SolrIndexSearcher Opening [Searcher@1e85b553[allprojects] main]
2016-12-23 06:55:17.535 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.r.ManagedResourceStorage File-based storage initialized to use dir: /home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects/conf
2016-12-23 06:55:17.535 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.c.SpellCheckComponent Initializing spell checkers
2016-12-23 06:55:17.535 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.s.DirectSolrSpellChecker init: {name=default,field=_text_,classname=solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker,distanceMeasure=internal,accuracy=0.5,maxEdits=2,minPrefix=1,maxInspections=5,minQueryLength=4,maxQueryFrequency=0.01}
2016-12-23 06:55:17.535 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.c.QueryElevationComponent Loading QueryElevation from: /home/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/solr/allprojects/conf/elevate.xml
2016-12-23 06:55:17.540 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.ReplicationHandler Commits will be reserved for  10000
2016-12-23 06:55:17.540 ERROR (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.d.DataImportHandler Exception while loading DataImporter
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:695)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:883)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:776)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:842)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:779)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$0(CoreAdminOperation.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$$Lambda$7/953742666.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:441)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-12-23 06:55:17.541 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [allprojects]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@7c82eb87
2016-12-23 06:55:17.541 INFO  (searcherExecutor-57-thread-1-processing-x:allprojects) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.QuerySenderListener QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@1e85b553[allprojects] main{ExitableDirectoryReader(UninvertingDirectoryReader())}
2016-12-23 06:55:17.541 INFO  (searcherExecutor-57-thread-1-processing-x:allprojects) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.QuerySenderListener QuerySenderListener done.
2016-12-23 06:55:17.541 INFO  (searcherExecutor-57-thread-1-processing-x:allprojects) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.c.SpellCheckComponent Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
2016-12-23 06:55:17.541 INFO  (searcherExecutor-57-thread-1-processing-x:allprojects) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [allprojects] Registered new searcher Searcher@1e85b553[allprojects] main{ExitableDirectoryReader(UninvertingDirectoryReader())}
2016-12-23 06:55:17.544 ERROR (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [allprojects]: Exception while loading DataImporter
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while loading DataImporter
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:903)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:776)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:842)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:779)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$0(CoreAdminOperation.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$$Lambda$7/953742666.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:441)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while loading DataImporter
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:695)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:883)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:88)
    ... 39 more
2016-12-23 06:55:17.545 ERROR (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'allprojects': Unable to create core [allprojects] Caused by: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:813)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$0(CoreAdminOperation.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$$Lambda$7/953742666.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:441)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [allprojects]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:855)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:779)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while loading DataImporter
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:903)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:776)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:842)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while loading DataImporter
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:695)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:883)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:88)
    ... 39 more

2016-12-23 06:55:17.545 INFO  (qtp2080166188-22) [   x:allprojects] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={schema=schema.xml&dataDir=data&name=allprojects&action=CREATE&config=solrconfig.xml&instanceDir=allprojects&wt=json&_=1482419054659} status=400 QTime=522
```

Comment: do you the jar "solr-dataimporthandler-6.1.0.jar" in your lib ? also please verify you entry of data-config.xml in solr-config.xml

Comment: `solr-dataimporthandler-4.0.0.jar`  `solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.0.0.jar`  `sqljdbc4-2.0.jar` are the jars i have. Do i mandatory require 6.1.0?

Comment: I think so...you need to have the right version...you will get those with solr only...

Comment: I think so...you need to have the right version...you will get those with solr only...check in the solr dist (solr-6.1.0/dist) folder you will get the jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delta-import for using multiple table in solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817414/delta-import-for-using-multiple-table-in-solr)